# Why pointer returns value, not adress?

Tags: c++, pointers

Why in my code I see **value**, which stored in the address, but not **adress**?

```
char *fortunes[] =
    {
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    };

    cout << *fortunes[2];   // result 3
    cout << fortunes[2];    // result 3, but I expected to see adress
```

Comment: do cout<< &(*fortunes[2])<<endl; like  this

Comment: why do you expect to see an address? - `cout << "3";`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: It is a pointer, so an address is not an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: well, it's also a C string.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, and OP does not know the overload for that. Thus the question.

Comment: I'm sure he *knows* it, he just hasn't realised that that's being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an overload for `std::ostream& operator<<` which takes a `const char*` and interprets it as a null-terminated string, printing out characters until it finds the null terminator. If you want to print the value of the pointer (the address it holds), you can cast it to `void*`.

For example

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<const void*>(fortunes[2]) << endl;
```

Comment: or to make it more obvious, as we use this overload all the time: `cout << "3";` - you wouldn't expect an address to be printed, would you?